# How can find bootable disc creator on Xubuntu 18.04?

Tags: usb, xubuntu, 18.04

I cant find bootable disc creator in xubuntu 18.04

Comment: USB Creator is a little bit 'deprecated'.  You might want to consider installing `dus` instead as an alternative to the USB Creator, as `dus` works fairly well (though it's a little bit less intuitive to use)

Comment: What app can you advice?

Answer (score 20):

It's not installed by default but available in the official repositories.
You can easily install it with

```
sudo apt install usb-creator-gtk
```

A shortcut to start the application will be created in the `System`-category in the start menu.